# Mysql inner join order the second table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, stores, promos, store_promo_link

I want to select 10 rows from stores. Stores must have 1 featured promo each, if there is no featured promo then select the latest promo

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stores` (
  `StoreID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StoreBranch` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `StoreName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IsFeatured` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OrderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StoreID`),
  KEY `StoreBranch` (`StoreBranch`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `StoreDesc` (`StoreDesc`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=51 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `promos` (
  `PromoID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text NOT NULL,
  `Photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IsFeatured` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `DateAdded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DateUpdated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PromoID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store_promo_link` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StoreID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PromoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=149 ;
```

this is my code but it is returning the first row from the promos

```
SELECT s.StoreBranch, s.StoreName, s.StoreID , p.* FROM `stores` s
INNER JOIN store_promo_link sp ON s.StoreID = sp.StoreID
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM promos ORDER BY IsFeatured DESC, DateAdded DESC) p ON sp.PromoID = p.PromoID
GROUP BY sp.StoreID
ORDER BY OrderNumber = 0, OrderNumber, s.IsFeatured DESC LIMIT 10
```

**EDIT**
I want to select 10 unique stores. Each store has multiple promos. I only want to select 1 featured (IsFeature = '1' ) promo for each store. If there is no featured promo, it must select the latest one.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have sample data?. Also edit FROM `store` s for FROM `stores` s, because store table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works fine. If the promo is featured you get it, if no featured promo, you get the last one. See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bec7f/1) I've written.

No store is duplicated:

```
StoreBranch     StoreName   StoreID     PromoID     Title   Description     Photo   IsFeatured  DateAdded   DateUpdated
be  ikea    1   2   2por1   promo2  foto2   1   September, 02 2015 00:00:00     September, 07 2015 10:48:54
es  mediamarkt  2   4   pollos  promo4  foto4   0   September, 04 2015 00:00:00     September, 07 2015 10:48:54
```

Comment: No, the result for stores is correct. Each store is  unique. There are multiple promos for each stores. I only want to select 1 promo for each store. The promo must be featured (IsFeatured = 1), if there is no featured promo, it must return the latest promo for that store.

Comment: Then your query works fine. In the SQLFiddle I've written, that's what you get. If the promo is featured, you get it, if no featured promo, you get the last one.

Comment: But the stores get duplicated. :(

Comment: it isn't... (updated answer) well, sorry, I don't see it. Add another example where we can see what's happening, because at the code I have I can't reproduce your issues

Comment: I don't see it. Can you update the link? tested it also on my localhost, the stores repeat

Comment: That's strange. That's my original code. but it's not working on my localhost. Thanks though